# Accessing objects uniformly

Tags: php, neo4j

This question is base on the facebook graph api...facebook is able to access objects (User, Page, Event) from a single URI...(graph.facebook.com/ID). How can I accomplish this using and neo4J? my plan is wrap each node type(User, Page, Event) in a php object then access all objects uniformly....

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have a uniform way to perform common operations on a set of objects of different type?

To do that in PHP, I would do two things - write an interface that defines the common operations, and then write proxy classes that, just like you mention, wrap the original objects and implement the interface.

For example, if you have these classes:

```
class User {
  public function getId() {
    // Return some id
  }

  // Other user-specific stuff here

}

class Event {
  public function getId() {
    // Return some id
  }

  // Other user-specific stuff here 

}
```

You could write an interface and two proxy classes like this:

```
interface FacebookObject {
  public function getId();
}

class UserProxy implements FacebookObject {
  function __construct($user) {
    $this->user = $user;
  }

  function getId() {
    return $this->user->getId();
  }
}

class EventProxy implements FacebookObject {
  function __construct($event) {
    $this->event = $event;
  }

  function getId() {
    return $this->event->getId();
  }
}
```

And then you can write code that operates on the FacebookObject proxy:

```
function getFacebookId(FacebookObject $obj) {
  return $obj->getId();
}
```